# Conflicting MVC Web Api Routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

We currently have a data setup like the following:

```
Task
 -> Incident
 -> ....
 -> ....
```

Quite a few objects are derived from a base class Task. We have built APIs to manage these objects, but also have some shared functionality which I attempting to put into a base api controller for each individual object api to inherit.

Like So

```
TaskController
 -> IncidentController
 -> ....
 -> ....
```

This works for the most part. I do have an issue with the following however.

Inside the `Incident Controller` I have a `Get` Method:

```
[RoutePrefix("Api/Incident")]
public class IncidentController : TaskController
{
    //Get an individual incident by ID
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id}")]
    public GenericIncidentGet Get(string id)
    {
        .....
    }
}
```

This method works fine. I then have a method on the parent controller

```
public class TaskController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{number}")]
    public ListResponse<TaskCiResultFlat> GetAffectedCIs(string number)
    {
        ......
    }
}
```

When I call the above method via /Api/Incident/GetAffectedCIs?number=XXXX it actually calls the `Incident Get()` Method but with a `null id` parameter.

I am currently registering these WebApi Routes:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
             "ActionIdApi", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id2}/{id3}/{id4}/{id5}/{id6}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, id2 = RouteParameter.Optional, id3 = RouteParameter.Optional, id4 = RouteParameter.Optional, id5 = RouteParameter.Optional, id6 = RouteParameter.Optional });


            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
 }
```

I can't quite figure out what is happening here.

Any suggestions?

Cheers.

Comment: Can you provide us route which you are using in postman to call above API?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I have added the API Call Url

Comment: did you get chance to look into my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the feedback from Karan and Prasad I have implemented the following solution:

IncidentController:

```
[RoutePrefix("Api/Incident")]
public class IncidentController : TaskController
{
    //Get an individual incident by ID
    [HttpGet]
    public GenericIncidentGet Get(string id)
    {
        return GenericIncidentWf.GenericIncidentGet(ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name, id);
    }
}
```

TaskController:

```
[RoutePrefix("Api/Incident")]
public class IncidentController : TaskController
{
    //Get an individual incident by ID
    [HttpGet]
    public GenericIncidentGet Get(string id)
    {
        return GenericIncidentWf.GenericIncidentGet(ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name, id);
    }
}
```

This works :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong API URL to call action method from *Incident controller*.

Action method contains `id` as a parameter, but when you are calling it through API URL, you are using `number` as a parameter name.

This URL, hitting to right API because type of parameter of `Id` and `number` is same, but passing null value to `Id`, because **you need to use `number` instead of `id` in API URL.**

To call Action method written in *Task Controller*, you can use

```
<BaseURL>/api/Task/Get?number=XXXX
```

To call action method written in *Incident Controller* , you can use

```
<BaseURL>/Api/Incident/GetAffectedCIs?id=XXXX
```

Hope my answer will resolve your problem

Answer (score 1):

@Prasad Telkikar has mentioned in his answer about why it get conflicts with routes.

You can make minor change to your `Route` value for `GetAffectedCIs` action as `[Route("GetAffectedCIs/{number}")]` then it will work.

Here `/Api/Incident/GetAffectedCIs?number=XXXX` will match to both APIs but as per the Route Order `[Route("GetAffectedCIs/{number}")]` has `Literal segments` as `GetAffectedCIs` and it has higher priority.

For more details about `Route Order` you can refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-order.

Your complete action will be as below.

```
public class TaskController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetAffectedCIs/{number}")]
    public ListResponse<TaskCiResultFlat> GetAffectedCIs(string number)
    {
        ......
    }
}
```